# Kramdown doesn't seem to render checkboxes like in GitHub

Tags: markdown, jekyll, kramdown

It seems Kramdown can recognise Github Flavoured Markdown in Jekyll. But it seems checkboxes that are available in GitHub isn't getting rendered using Kramdown, any ideas why?

What I am trying to do:

```
- [ ] Unchecked
- [x] Checked
```

This would show up as disabled checkboxes in GitHub but not so in Jekyll.

Comment: Sorry but it seems that this feature won't be implemented when [another OP requested it](https://github.com/gettalong/kramdown/issues/172). Also a workaround is suggested

Answer (score 4):

This is what the instructions on the [official website](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/) say. Just try it, maybe it works then.

In addition to the defaults mentioned above, you can also turn on recognition of Github Flavored Markdown by passing an input option with a value of “GFM”.

For example, in your `_config.yml`:

```
kramdown:
  input: GFM
```

Source: http://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/#kramdown